# Unable to install the googleads module for python in anaconda (Spyder)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder, google-ads-api

I am trying to use the python googleads module in a script on Spyder.

I have run `pip install googleads` and the installation has succeeded.

However, when I try to `import googleads` in the script on Spyder, it gives me the below error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleads'`

I have uninstalled the package and run `pip install googleads` again. The installation succeeds this time as well but the above error persists.

I have tried using conda install as well. That does not install the package.

However, when I run the script on the command prompt, it works fine. The issue is only with Spyder.

I have also Googled and looked up StackOverflow and most other communities for a solution to this but haven't been able to find one :(

Looking forward to some help here, to fix the issue.

Thank you in advance!

PS: I have run the pip install on the Anaconda prompt as well and that succeeds too. The error on Spyder still exists.

Comment: Are you certain that you're using the correct Python installation (the one where you installed the packages, obviously) ? _I have uninstalled the package and run pip install googleads again._ Be careful. Have you read https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/ ?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-PyQt-applications-within-Spyder) to understand how to fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you @AMC and Carlos for your help :)  I was using the correct python installation and only use pip for installation when conda packages are not available. I have posted the solution to my issue in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I hired a freelancer with considerable experience in Anaconda and Spyder to help me fix this issue. Sharing the solution here for the benefit of everyone else.

There was an issue with the installation of pip in the environment I was working in. This is how we found and fixed the issue:

On the Anaconda prompt, we used the command `conda list` and checked if pip was installed. It was.

We then typed the command `where pip` and received the response below:
C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe

We then created a new test environment in anaconda, navigated to it and ran the same `where pip` command. It returned the below response:
C:\Users\Rohit\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe

We figured that there was an issue with the pip installation on the environment, which is why it was installing the packages on the global environment and not the project environment.

We then re-installed pip on the project environment using the conda install and re-ran the `where pip` command. It now returned the below response:
C:\Users\Rohit\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe

After this, we installed the package using `pip install googleads` and then ran `import googleads` in Spyder. It worked perfectly fine.

Works fine now with all the other project packages.